# Como eliminar un archivo especifico de un Array?

Tags: javascript

Tengo dos **botones** imput file que guardan un archivo por cada uno.

Cree un Array global donde cada vez que hay un onchange en alguno de los dos botones se vaya guardando el archivo.

Existen dos botones "remove", en tal caso como podria eliminar el archivo especifico que quitó?

```
 <input type="button" value="Eliminar Archivo" id="clear1" class="clear" style="color:black; float: left;" onclick="obj=document.getElementById('control1');obj.value='';obj.disabled=false">
 <input type="file" name="UploadFile1" id="control1" class="UploadFile1" style="float: left;" onchange="this.disabled=true;">

<input type="button" value="Eliminar Archivo" id="clear2" class="clear" style="color:black; float: left;" onclick="obj=document.getElementById('control2');obj.value='';obj.disabled=false">
<input type="file" name="UploadFile2" id="control2" class="UploadFile2" style="float: left;" onchange="this.disabled=true;">
```

Javascript:

```
    var FileArray = [];

    $("#clear1").hide();

    var UploadFile1 = $("#control1"),
        clearBn1 = $("#clear1");

    clearBn1.on("click", function () {
        UploadFile1.replaceWith(UploadFile1.val(''));
    });

    $('#clear1').on('click', function (e) {
        $("#clear1").hide();
    });

    $("#clear2").hide();

    var UploadFile2 = $("#control2"),
        clearBn2 = $("#clear2");

    clearBn2.on("click", function () {
        UploadFile2.replaceWith(UploadFile2.val(''));
    });

    $('#clear2').on('click', function (e) {
        $("#clear2").hide();
    });

    $('.UploadFile1').on('change', function (e) {
        $("#clear1").show();
        var files = e.target.files;
        if (files.length > 0)
        {
            FileArray.push(files);
        }
    });

    $('.UploadFile2').on('change', function (e) {
        $("#clear2").show();
        var files = e.target.files;
        if (files.length > 0) {

            FileArray.push(files);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Porque hay dos botones para remover algo del array? Porque no uno solo?

Comment: El usuario presiona el boton1 sube una imagen (sera la preview-icono). automaticamente se bloquea y aparece un boton remover ese file.    En paralelo hay un boton2 donde puede subir una imagen y el proceso es el mismo (sera la imagen de posteo)

Comment: Para eliminar algún ítem de un array. Usa [`.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/slice).

Comment: Opte por crear dos arrays por separado donde cada uno agrega o borra los files de los imputs. Y en el evento this on submit le digo que concatene los resultados de esos dos arrays.

Comment: Es mi idea o estas añadiendo dos vecez eventos  de un mismo tipo a los botones?, sería buena idea unificar esos dos eventos.

Comment: Amigo, en el input tipo file existe un atributo llamado multiple, que te permite subir varios archivos a la vez, si vas a de todas maneras a añadir varios elementos a una lista, entonces por que no mejor usar un solo input tipo file y varios botones para eliminar cada archivo?, de todas maneras para que el usuario pueda eliminar un archivo que añadio a la lista, debe haber algo que le muestre los archivos que añadio y un boton a su lado por ejemplo, en cada uno de estos para que pueda darle click y eliminarlo, es decir, te propongo que no uses dos input file, usa uno solo.

Answer (score 2):

Voy a simplificar todo un poco,te propongo una mejor solucion poniendo solo lo necesario, bien partamos de lo siguiente:

tenemos inicialmente un solo input file:

```
<input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="uploadFile" onchange = "addFiles(event)" multiple>
```

y debajo tenemos una lista vacia:

```
<ul id = "listaArchivos">
</ul>
```

A continuación desde javascript añadimos los archivos de la siguiente manera:

```js
let fileArray = [];
let listaArchivos = $("#listaArchivos")[0];


function clearFile(ev){
    const parent = ev.currentTarget.parentElement;

    const index = parseInt(parent.id.split("_")[1]);
    fileArray.splice(index, 1);

    listaArchivos.removeChild(parent);
}

function addFiles(ev){

    const fileList = ev.currentTarget.files;
    
    for(let file of fileList){
        fileArray.push(file);

        const newFile = document.createElement("li");
        const text = document.createTextNode(file.name);
        
        newFile.id = `file_${fileArray.length - 1}`;
        newFile.appendChild(text);

        const clearBtn = document.createElement("input");
        clearBtn.style.marginLeft = "20px";
        clearBtn.type = "button";
        clearBtn.value = "Remover archivo";
        clearBtn.onclick = ev => clearFile(ev);

        newFile.appendChild(clearBtn);
        listaArchivos.appendChild(newFile);
    }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="uploadFile" onchange = "addFiles(event)" multiple>

<ul id = "listaArchivos"></ul>
```

Podemos ver como es posible añadir y eliminar archivos desde un solo input file haciendo uso de multiples botones, a su vez, estos elementos al ser eliminados se eliminan tambien en el array de archivos.

Comment: Lo probé, se eliminan de la visualmente pero siempre están en el arreglo de archivos!

Comment: No puedes eliminar archivos seleccionados del input file,  en su lugar debes eliminar son los que tu guardaste en otro arreglo aparte (por eso tengo declarada la variable fileArray), tienes que usar es un array propio que contenga los archivos ya que ese contiene los metodos para realizar dicha operacion,  no debes usar entonces el contenido del input file.